# Cannot use SQLite Row objects with multiprocessing library

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn how to use SQLite and multiprocessing library in Python. Maybe my problem is very simple but I can't figure out how to change my program to make it work.

I have following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

from db import get_db

def _getDbData():
    db = get_db()
    rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM table')

    return rows.fetchall()


def _taskPut(row_tuple, queue, flag):
    for i in range(5):
        queue.put((row_tuple[0], i))
        print(' * inserted values: ', row_tuple[0], i)
        time.sleep(0.75)


def _taskGet(queue):
    while queue.qsize():
        print(queue.get())


def runTasks():
    consoles= _getDbData()

    with multiprocessing.Manager() as process_mgr:
        # Create shared Queue and iterable with function arguments
        events_queue= process_mgr.Queue()
        args= zip( [tuple(i) for i in consoles], [events_queue]*len(consoles), [False]*len(consoles) )

        pool= multiprocessing.Pool()
        pool.map(_taskPut, zip(consoles, args))
        pool.map(_takGet, (events_queue,))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

I'm getting error: `TypeError: can't pickle sqlite3.Row objects`. I don't understand why I'm getting this error, because I don't pass `sqlite3.Row` but `tuple`.

PS: `_taskPut` and `_taskGet` are dummy functions, since I just wanted to test how multiprocessing works.